# What does numpy do in assignment?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose that I have a code shown below

```py
import numpy as np
n = 100
a = np.empty((n,))
b = np.random.random((n,))
c = np.random.random((n,))

def sum(x, y):
    return x + y

# assignment 1
a = b + c

# assignment 2
a = sum(b, c)

# assignment 3
d = b + c

# assignment 4
b = b + c
```

I wonder what numpy does for each assignment?

- For assignment 1 and 2, does it make a temporary array first, then copy the content to `a`? Or does it calculate `b + c` and directly store the result to `a`?
- For assignment 3, does it initialize `d` and directly store the result of `b + c` to `d`?
- For assignment 4, does it create a temporary variable or just modify `b` in place (equivalent to write `b += c`)?

It does not matter much for small number of `n`, but once it reaches `10^7` or above, I think this could matter a lot in terms of speed.

Comment: there is no concept of copying "into" a. this is python, names are just that, names. They refer to values/objects. things are evaluated on the right hand side, and its only putting labels or names on the left hand side.

Comment: So there's no temporary object in assignment 1-3? How about assignment 4?

Comment: because of the difference between names and objects/values, there is zero difference between 3 and 4. Just, 4 happens to take a label off of the original contents of whatever `b` was pointing to. (and so it should eventually be garbage collected if no other references exist)

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Standard CPython is reference-counted, so there is a difference in 1, 2 and 3 inasmuch they result in the destruction of the previously referenced object (I don't know if there are any provisions within NumPy to minimize the impact of this, though).

Comment: aye, but i think here it is important to directly target OP's mistaken assumption about the real problem at hand, the idea of "temporary objects being created, and then copied over into the real object `a` ", the problem being, `a` is just a name. Reference counting and how object deletion happens should only be added to the discussion once the main issue is addressed.

Comment: This [link](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) should help understand and clarify this distinction between names and values.

Comment: `a[:] = ...` copies values from RHS to the existing array.  `a= ...` is variable assignment without further copying.

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/ma/core.py#L5034 I would say the solution in somewhere near here, but I am just guessing